# How to decrease the learning rate only when cost function is stagnant?

Tags: tensorflow, cost-function, learning-rate

I'm training a very complex function in tensorflow. Is there a way to decrease the learning rate only when the cost isin't decreasing very much?

Comment: Just keep track of the objective function and use a conditional to set the leraning rate if it drops.

Comment: I couldn't do it in tensorflow, is there any example of how something like this is done in tensorflow?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage